# android sqlite group by clause

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i want to write a query to get last message send or receive to each contact. but unfortunalty group by clause is creating some issue like by writing the following query i get the last message that is send to a contact and if no message send to a contact then the last receive message is return by this query.

```
String where = "type=? OR type=? ) GROUP BY ( thread_id ";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { "" + Constants.SMS_RECEIVE,
            "" + Constants.SMS_SENT };

    try {
        Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(Constants.URI_SMS,
                smsProjection, where, whereArgs, "date DESC");
```

and if i remove the group by clause i get all the messages send or receive to a contact.

```
    String where = "type=? OR type=? ";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { "" + Constants.SMS_RECEIVE,
            "" + Constants.SMS_SENT };

    try {
        Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(Constants.URI_SMS,
                smsProjection, where, whereArgs, "date DESC");
```

the resone of using group by clause is that why fetch un related records from database.

Answer (score 0):

When you do GROUP BY you can get surprising results for fields, it's really most useful for aggregate functions like SUM() or COUNT(). Depending on how you need to handle multiple contacts, you could ORDER BY (some date field) DESC and then use LIMIT to get just the single most recent entry.